# Can I use ASP.NET MVC Partial in my case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I new to ASP.NET MVC so this question maybe simple for you but please give me more detail :)

In my app there is a Menu, all of this Menu Item store in Database, the Menu showing every pages. I think what I need is Partial but I not sure how!

BTW I can always use ajax, so which way is better?

Thanks for yout time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need this to be a partial view, you can generate it in run time using regular .net code if you have a proper helper function. Anyways, for your question you can do these in a couple of ways.

- Create a partial view and load it using the partial tag

  ```
  @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
  ```
- or you can write a Html helper function

  ```
  public static string GetMenus(this HtmlHelper html)
  {
       //Generate your menu in HTML format
  }
  ```

  and render it using the html renderer

  ```
  @Html.Raw(Html.GetMenus())
  ```
- For ajax, you can also write some function which does the same work of GetMenu and call it using an Ajax get.

  ```
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Controller/YourGetMenu',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          data: { ParameterName: itemvalue },
          success: function (data) {
              //Do the menu rendering work
                },
          error: function (ex) {
              alert('Error.');
          }

      });
  ```

I would go for the second option.